# Convert List of tuple to map (and deal with duplicate key ?)

Tags: scala, dictionary

I was thinking about a nice way to convert a List of tuple with duplicate key `[("a","b"),("c","d"),("a","f")]` into map `("a" -> ["b", "f"], "c" -> ["d"])`. Normally (in python), I'd create an empty map and for-loop over the list and check for duplicate key. But I am looking for something more scala-ish and clever solution here.

btw, actual type of key-value I use here is `(Int, Node)` and I want to turn into a map of `(Int -> NodeSeq)`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Group and then project:

```
scala> val x = List("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "a" -> "f")
//x: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((a,b), (c,d), (a,f))
scala> x.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}
//res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,List[java.lang.String]] = Map(c -> List(d), a -> List(b, f))
```

More scalish way to use fold, in the way like [there](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/09/13/cluster-by/) (skip `map f` step).

Answer (score 140):

For people that don't expect duplicates or are fine with the [default duplicate handling policy](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#toMap%5BT,U%5D:scala.collection.Map%5BT,U%5D):

```
List("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "a" -> 3).toMap
// Result: Map(a -> 3, b -> 2)
```

As of 2.12, the default policy reads:

> Duplicate keys will be overwritten by later keys: if this is an unordered collection, which key is in the resulting map is undefined.

Answer (score 59):

Here's another alternative:

```
x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: This gives us a `Map[String, SeqView[String,Seq[_]]]`... is this intentional?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge A `SeqView[String,Seq[_]]` is also a `Seq[String]`. Still in hindsight I don't think that is worthwhile, so I removed the `view`. `mapValues` will do a view anyway on the values.

Comment: This did the job perfectly for my case (coursera homework):

  lazy val dictionaryByOccurrences: Map[Occurrences, List[Word]] = {

    val pairs = for (curWord <- dictionary) yield {
      val curWordOccurrences = wordOccurrences(curWord)
      (curWordOccurrences, curWord)
    }

    pairs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  }

Comment: mapValues returns a view of a map, not a new map http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map

Comment: Probably want `x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map(identity)` because the `mapValues` expression will be recomputed each time it is used. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7005

Answer (score 20):

For Googlers that do care about duplicates:

```
implicit class Pairs[A, B](p: List[(A, B)]) {
  def toMultiMap: Map[A, List[B]] = p.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
}

> List("a" -> "b", "a" -> "c", "d" -> "e").toMultiMap
> Map("a" -> List("b", "c"), "d" -> List("e"))
```

Answer (score 20):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are provided with the [groupMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent (more efficient) of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues`:

```
List("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "a" -> "f").groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map[String,List[String]] = Map(a -> List(b, f), c -> List(d))
```

This:

- `group`s elements based on the first part of tuples (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped values by taking their second tuple part (map part of group**Map**)

This is an equivalent of `list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))` but [performed in one pass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L578) through the List.

Answer (score 6):

**Below you can find a few solutions. (GroupBy, FoldLeft, Aggregate, Spark)**

```
val list: List[(String, String)] = List(("a","b"),("c","d"),("a","f"))
```

**GroupBy variation**

```
list.groupBy(_._1).map(v => (v._1, v._2.map(_._2)))
```

**Fold Left variation**

```
list.foldLeft[Map[String, List[String]]](Map())((acc, value) => {
  acc.get(value._1).fold(acc ++ Map(value._1 -> List(value._2))){ v =>
    acc ++ Map(value._1 -> (value._2 :: v))
  }
})
```

**Aggregate Variation - Similar to fold Left**

```
list.aggregate[Map[String, List[String]]](Map())(
  (acc, value) => acc.get(value._1).fold(acc ++ Map(value._1 -> 
    List(value._2))){ v =>
     acc ++ Map(value._1 -> (value._2 :: v))
  },
  (l, r) => l ++ r
)
```

**Spark Variation - For big data sets (Conversion to a RDD and to a Plain Map from RDD)**

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

val conf: SparkConf = new 
SparkConf().setAppName("Spark").setMaster("local")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext (conf)

// This gives you a rdd of the same result
val rdd: RDD[(String, List[String])] = sc.parallelize(list).combineByKey(
   (value: String) => List(value),
   (acc: List[String], value) => value :: acc,
   (accLeft: List[String], accRight: List[String]) => accLeft ::: accRight
)

// To convert this RDD back to a Map[(String, List[String])] you can do the following
rdd.collect().toMap
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more Scala idiomatic way to convert a list of tuples to a map handling duplicate keys. You want to use a fold.

```
val x = List("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "a" -> "f")

x.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
  acc.updated(k, acc.getOrElse(k, Seq.empty[String]) ++ Seq(v))
}

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]] = Map(a -> List(b, f), c -> List(d))
```

Comment: Why do you think this is more Scala-style than the groupBy-mapValue solutions provided here?

Comment: @om-nom-nom statement "More scalish way to use fold, in the way like there (skip map f step)."

Comment: I was hoping for a logical argument ;-). Neither om-nom-nom nor the linked article provided evidence for my question. (Or did I miss it?)

Comment: @Make42 It's a more fp way to deal with this, since all monads are monoids, and monoids by law are foldable. In fp, objects and events are modeled as monads, and not all monads will implement groupBy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
scala> val b = new Array[Int](3)
// b: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0)
scala> val c = b.map(x => (x -> x * 2))
// c: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (2,4), (3,6))
scala> val d = Map(c : _*)
// d: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6)
```

Comment: how does this 'deal with duplicate key' ?