# How to idiomatically turn a Seq of tuples into a Map in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have this

```
list {
  1,1
  1,2
  2,1
}
```

and I want to turn it into this

```
map {
  1 -> (1,2)
  2 -> (1)
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
val list = List((1,1),(1,2),(2,1))
var map: Map[Int, Seq[Int]] = Map()

for (e <- list) {
   if (map contains e._1)
    map = map + (e._1 -> (map(e._1) :+ e._2))
  else
    map = map + (e._1 -> Seq(e._2))
}
```

Needless to say it looks like someone spilled milk on my code.
How to improve the situation?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016750/convert-list-of-tuple-to-map-and-deal-with-duplicate-key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `.groupBy` method:

```
scala> val list = List((1,1),(1,2),(2,1))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (2,1))

scala> val map = list.groupBy(_._1)
map: Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(2 -> List((2,1)), 1 -> List((1,1), (1,2)))
```

Then you simply need to map over the values and select the second element of each couple:

```
scala> val map = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
map: Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(1), 1 -> List(1, 2))
```