# Convert List of Object to Map with duplicate key

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a class that looks like this:

```
case class Person(id : String, name : String, refId : String) {}
```

And I have a list of Person.

I want to have a map with 
key = refId 
value = List[Person]    that have the same refId **(duplicate keys)**

What I did:

```
val persons = getPersons() // get the List from somewhere
val refMap = new mutable.HashMap[String,Seq[Person]]()
for (person<- persons){
  refMap.put(person.refId,refMap.getOrElse(person.refId,new ArrayBuffer[Person]) :+ person)
}
```

That was my first idea and it work, but I want something more Scala-like or something that looks better. Do you have an idea?

I also tried what is written here: [Convert List of tuple to map (and deal with duplicate key ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016750/convert-list-of-tuple-to-map-and-deal-with-duplicate-key)

But they use Tuple and I couldn't get this work either.
I also tried it to map my list to tuples first but 
1. I don't want to iterate 2 times over the List when it's not necessary (1 time to create tuples, 1 time to create the map.
2. I tried but I failed with tuples too.

Any help for a better code would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [groupBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]):

```
getPersons().groupBy(_.refId): Map[String, List[Person]]
```