# Convert list to map in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert list to map and getting error which is given below,Any help will be appreciated.

My input like this

```
list=(ageis=21,nameis="xyz",profession="Tester",city="cuba")
```

I wanted output like this

```
Map(ageis->21,nameis->"xyz",profession->"Tester",city->"cuba")
```

Comment: The `list` value you defined does not compile. Please replace it with a real value, so we may understand what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet this for the correction,please see the updated above.

Comment: Is that a list of tuples?

Comment: This still isn't parseable scala code. There is no construct where you can freely use identifiers such as  `age`, `name` and so on without at least some more context (and even then, eg in case classes, the syntax would be different).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016750/convert-list-of-tuple-to-map-and-deal-with-duplicate-key

Comment: @freedev i have tried method which i in above link and got error.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it is list.

Comment: A List of what?

Comment: not clear what error you had...

Comment: is your input a string?

Comment: @freedev the error is Error:(1, 25) value _1 is not a member of String
  val m =list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}

Comment: @the hacker, please update your question showing what's the exactly is `list`. The error you have mostly depends of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example if you input is:

```
val list = List("age=21", "name=xyz", "profession=Tester", "city=cuba")
```

The easier way I can think to have a map:

```
val myMap = myList.map(text => text.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a string

```
val input = """list=(ageis=21,nameis="xyz",profession="Tester",city="cuba")"""
```

then you can do

```
val myMap =
  input
    .stripPrefix("list=(")
    .stripSuffix(")")
    .split(",")
    .map { entry =>
      val Array(key, value) = entry.split("=")
     (key, value.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\""))
    }.toMap
```

Result

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a small 'Type Safe' version for you to future proof the data you receive.

If there is any data in the string field that does not contain the delimiter or breaks it will not be contained in the resulting Map.

You can then afterwards use .get(): Option[String] to retrieve a result. (If that result is within the map)

```
val list: List[String] = List("ageis=21", "nameis=xyz", "profession=Tester", "city=cuba")
list.splitToMap()


trait CustomToMapTrait {
  def splitToMap (delimiter: String = "="): Map[String, String]
}


/**
 * Some Type safety for implemented for the parsing. If there is no delimiter available or the text is incorrect it will not be included in the map.
 * This saves you from improper data going through your system.
 *
 * Added some functionality so that you can add your own custom delimiter for if it should change
 */

implicit def splitToMap (list: List[String]): CustomToMapTrait = new CustomToMapTrait {
  private def toOptionMap (values: List[String]): Option[Map[String, String]] = {
    if (values.length == 2) values.headOption.fold[Option[Map[String, String]]](None)(l => values.lift(1).fold[Option[Map[String, String]]](None)(r => Some(Map(l -> r))))
    else None
  }
  override def splitToMap (delimiter: String = "="): Map[String, String] = {
    list.foldLeft[Map[String, String]](Map())((acc, value) => toOptionMap(value.split(delimiter).toList).fold(acc)(_ ++ acc))
  }
}
```